# Models for simulating FX movements

Tags: fx, monte-carlo, simulations, modelling

My goal is to develop a model to simulate long term FX movements. (I am not sure if long term makes any difference, but if it does I am more interested in long term fx movements)

These Monte Carlo simulations will *not* be used for pricing but from a risk-management perspective, to calculate how much the portfolio is exposed to FX risk.

I was wondering if there is a suggested model (or paper or anything) that I could use as a starting base.

**Some further notes, after Matt's comment:**

I am not interested in some sort of a trading strategy (i think i misused the words: portfolio and exposure). And i don't want to hedge or price anything.

Imagine that you have lend some money (through some instrument) that you will receive in 20-30 years in a foreign currency.  Now you believe that forex rates have some correlation with your instrument and some other factors and you want to see how much you stand to lose in a worst case scenario.

My idea was that I would run an MC where i will have some sort of forex evolution correlated with the evolution of my instrument and i set up some sort of a stress test.

Is my line of thinking correct, or you believe that i should be trying something else?

If we agree that my approach is decent, my question is how would you evolve a forex rate.

Comment: You do not need a forecasting model to calculate your portfolio risk exposure. Aside that this site is not a repository for trading strategies, one of the hardest earned asset. If you need to calculate fx exposure for portfolios simple map out each asset in the portfolio and group its notional exposure (or delta for options) by currency to get what you want. For trading strategies I recommend to look elsewhere because I am pretty sure most users are more than hesitant to hand you the fruits of their hard labor free of charge.

Comment: Hi Matt,

thank you for your answer. I've been reading this site for some time and i've learn a ton from your answers. I think i didn't phrase my question correctly. Please bear with me, I am still a student, I will try to reformat my question.

Comment: @following your edit, could you please pose a specific example. What do you mean with "instrument"? Your worst case is a perfect correlation of your "instrument" with the "foreign" currency you receive back in x years and if I understand correctly you look to model the future paths of that currency? Worst case then is a massive devaluation of such currency vs your base currency. You can use an fx model to simulate such paths but I tell you upfront that you will not gain much with that. Long-term fx rates are heavily a function of fundamentals such as monetary policy, nations' debt servicing...

Comment: I see that I abused terminology one more time.  by worst case i meant: an average (expected) loss for some parameters.
In terms of instrument, what i have in mind is pretty simple.


Along the lines of having euros or dollars and lending really long term money in some "weird" currency. This practically means that you can't really hedge the forex risk.  I didn't want to convolute the example that's why i avoided being super specific.

Comment: You say: "You can use an fx model to simulate such paths but I tell you upfront that you will not gain much with that" So people don't model forex or it is the long term that breaks the situation? (any papers/books/articles on the subject would be extremely appreciated)

Comment: Ok, I tell you how it is, then you can still dig out the annual Bloomberg article on the top fx forecasters. You put 200 apes into a room. You ask each of them where they see USDJPY a year from now. A year later you find out that 10/200 apes were relatively close in their estimate to the actual rate. Same game repeated...a year later 1/10 again hits the jackpot. That guy is pronounced the king of fx analysts. Chance? Talent? I chuckle each time I come across the same spiel. If I saw the same guy in the top 3 over 5-10 years I would resort it to talen but not 1-2 data observations.

Comment: A case i have in my mind is the following (where you have correlation with defaults and forex):
When an economy goes through some rough patches, the associated currency devaluates but at the same time the probability for the default of a company increases.

Comment: ...why I said that? Because forecasting future asset prices with volatility patterns such as currencies a year out is all but throwing darts blindfolded. There are many animals in this industry, however, 90-95% are those little fish that stay close to the primal hunter who generates reliable alpha for the rest. I probably have come across 10 analysts that I find noteworthy of reading and listening to out of at least 500-800 I got in contact with over the past 10 years.

Comment: ...well then just specify a model based on fundamentals. Use the usual suspects such as short term rate, 1-5/1-10 spreads, gdp growth, employment, trade balance, throw in some qualitative factors such as "war-risk", "qantitative easing risk" (lol, forget that last one), and fit this multifactor model to past fx rates and see what you get. You can google "currency forecasting pdf" and should find tons of papers.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks again for all your help. Apologies if my questions don't make a lot of sense, i am just starting in the field.  

So, I know that predicting forex movement is impossible but i guess the same applies for the stocks but we do have models that capture their various dynamics, right?

Comment: Are there any equivalent SDEs that capture the dynamics of the forex.

For example here:
http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/390/Lecture9.pdf

they use GBM dynamics, if I am not mistaken Shreve in his book also uses GBM dynamics. But it seems to simple of a model.

Searching online I've found some stuff for long-dated forex option pricing (including this Foreign Exchange Option Pricing by Iain Clark) but I am not sure how useful they will be in my case.

Comment: As to building a statistical model with various factors, I am not actually sure if this is the best solution given that I want to do a Monte Carlo Simulation to find average loss

Comment: I cannot say more than recommending you again to look at a multi-factor model with parameters fit to past currency return dynamics. Please do report back your findings after playing with some of the factors, I would be curious about your work.

Comment: Will do that! As a general question ,in the real world, when would you model using a multi-factor model and when using SDEs ?